# Error code 450 Requested mail action not taken: mailbox unavailable when send email laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I want to send email to user. I have created using gmail smtp setting and it's working normally but when I tried send email using yahoo smtp setting it's not working and show error code like below

```
 Swift_TransportException (450)
Expected response code 250 but got code "450", with message "450     Requested mail action not taken: mailbox unavailable "
```

I've cache config laravel using php artisan config:cache but it's still not working as normal as gmail settings

Here's .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@yahoo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Do you know if there's any settings that I forgot ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sending it from local server?

Comment: Hi @OsamaAlvi, yeah, I am sending it from my computer (local server)

Comment: check my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try restart your server and try again and also show your credentials in your env file.

Probably you need to enable below option from your yahoo account:

Account Security -> Allow apps that use less secure sign in